# Pythonnet unable to call VB.NET function with collection argument

Tags: python, .net, vb.net, python.net

I'm having an issue trying to call `TestFunc` as I'm getting `TypeError: No method matches given arguments for TestFunc`.

My python code looks like so:

```
import sys
import clr

sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Me\Projects\Dependencies\bin')
clr.AddReference('iCamstar')

from iCamstar import CamstarUtil

containers = []
camStar = CamstarUtil(host, port, username, password, workstation)
response = camStar.TestFunc(containers)
print(response)
```

and the VB.NET code looks like so:

```
...
Public Class CamstarUtil

  Public Structure MyContainer
    Dim ctnrName As String
    Dim productName As String
    Dim specName As String
    Dim description As String
    ...
  End Structure

  Public Sub New (ByVal host As String, ByVal port As String, ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String, ByVal ws As String)
    ...
  End Sub

  Public Function TestFunc(ByVal containers As Collection(Of MyContainer))
    Return "Foo Bar"
  End Function

  ...
```

The VB.NET code is not able to be modified, it is a shared library.  I have tried what is shown above and tried:

```
from System import Array
py_array = []
net_array = Array[int](py_array)
response = camStar.TestFunc(net_array)
```

and that did not work either.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

EDIT: I have just tried doing this route:

```
clr.AddReference('System.Collections')
...
from System.Collections import *
...
containers = ArrayList()
...
```

This did not work either

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by importing the correct Collection type:

```
from System.Collections.ObjectModel import Collection
...
containers = Collection[CamstarUtil.myContainer]()
...
```

It turned out it was not a Generic collection type!